# How to get Printer Info in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printers, printdialog

In the standard PrintDialog there are four values associated with a selected printer: Status, Type, Where, and Comment.

If I know a printer's name, how can I get these values in C# 2.0?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As [dowski suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-cnet#296232), you could use WMI to get printer properties. The following code displays all properties for a given printer name. Among them you will find: PrinterStatus, Comment, Location, DriverName, PortName, etc.

```
using System.Management;
```

...

```
string printerName = "YourPrinterName";
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
using (ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get())
{
    try
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
        {
            foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

This *should* work.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

...

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
ps.PrinterName = "The printer name"; // Load the appropriate printer's setting
```

After that, the various [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings_members(VS.80).aspx) of PrinterSettings can be read.

Note that `ps.isValid()` can see if the printer actually exists.

Edit:  One additional comment.  Microsoft recommends you use a [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(VS.80).aspx) and modify its PrinterSettings rather than creating a PrinterSettings directly.

Comment: This doesn't work. In my case it doesn't update the properties (for example CanDuplex). Also, the documentation says that `IsDefaultPrinter` "Gets a value indicating whether the PrinterName property designates the default printer, except when the user explicitly sets PrinterName."

Answer (score 7):

Look at [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a list of all the available properties for a printer ManagementObject.

```
usage: printer.Properties["PropName"].Value
```

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I've worked in a Windows environment, but I would suggest that you look at [using WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Please notice that the article that ***dowski*** and ***Panos*** was reffering to ([MSDN Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx)) can be a little misleading.

I'm referring the first value of most of the arrays. some begins with 1 and some begins with 0.
for example, "*ExtendedPrinterStatus*" first value in table is 1, therefore, your array should be something like this:

```
string[] arrExtendedPrinterStatus = { 
    "","Other", "Unknown", "Idle", "Printing", "Warming Up",
    "Stopped Printing", "Offline", "Paused", "Error", "Busy",
    "Not Available", "Waiting", "Processing", "Initialization",
    "Power Save", "Pending Deletion", "I/O Active", "Manual Feed"
};
```

and on the other hand, "*ErrorState*" first value in table is 0, therefore, your array should be something like this:

```
string[] arrErrorState = {
    "Unknown", "Other", "No Error", "Low Paper", "No Paper", "Low Toner",
    "No Toner", "Door Open", "Jammed", "Offline", "Service Requested",
    "Output Bin Full"
};
```

BTW,
"*PrinterState*" is obsolete, but you can use "*PrinterStatus*".

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old posting, but nowadays the easier/quicker option is to use the enhanced printing services offered by the WPF framework (usable by non-WPF apps).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing(v=vs.110).aspx

An example to retrieve the status of the printer queue and first job..

```
var queue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Printer Name");
var queueStatus = queue.QueueStatus;
var jobStatus = queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().FirstOrDefault().JobStatus
```

Comment: Both LocalPrintServer and the queue returned from GetPrintQueue are IDisposable so you should really wrap that in a using call.                using (var lps = new LocalPrintServer())
            {
                using (var queue = lps.GetPrintQueue(printerName))
                {
                    var queueStatus = queue.QueueStatus;
                    var jobStatus = queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().FirstOrDefault().JobStatus;
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to WMI you can get fast accurate results by tapping in to WinSpool.drv (i.e. Windows API) - you can get all the details on the interfaces, structs & constants from pinvoke.net, or I've put the code together at http://delradiesdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/accessing-printer-status-using-winspool.html