# Loading Printer Name

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I want to write code in C# for loading printer name in window. But I don't have any ideas to write it.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks. Ung Sopolin

Answer (score 0):

Include a reference to the `System.Drawing` library and then:

```
var printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>();

foreach (var printer in printers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printer);
}
```

I think you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-c-net) post.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PrinterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings_members(VS.71).aspx) class from the [System.Drawing.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(VS.71).aspx) namespace

`PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`

should return you a list of Printers.

Answer (score 0):

PrinterSettings prSetting = new PrinterSettings();

Then prSetting.PrinterName will get you the name of the default printer name. You can use the same class for other Printer information.