# PrintDialog.PrinterSettings below .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, wpf

PrintDialog in .NET 3.5 hasnt a filed PrinterSettings. How can I set PrinterName and similar things in .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PrintDialog.PrinterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.printersettings.aspx) property has been around since .NET 1.0

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm referring to this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Please tag your question correctly.  It doesn't exist in WPF because PrinterSettings is not a WPF class.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters(VS.90).aspx), it says it is supported in 3.5

Edit: you can also use [WMI queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net):