# Is there a way to read the Driver type property from code

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Printer Info in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net)

In my C# program i would like to get the model  of the printer. Please tell me how is it possible. Please see the screen shot. I need the text underneath the red rectangle

[image]

Comment: Did you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net

Comment: That approaches dont give information on Model name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [post mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net) has all the code you need. However, what you are looking for maybe referred to by a  different printer property name.

If you have got the code running, try looking up: `Caption`, `Name` and `DeviceID` properties. You should get what you want.