# fetch information from USB printers

Tags: c#, java, vbscript, wmi, snmp

I want to discover local printer (attached via USB) through any java or .net application. i need following information directly from the printer.
1. printer make and model
2. serial number
3. page count

I have tried SNMP API in java but it works for networked printer only. I am searching for any API or script that communicate with USB printer and provide me information.

till now, i have tried WMI queries but through these queries, I am not able to fetch page count and serial number values from USB printer.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Part of the answer you should find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{

foreach (String printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)

{

printersList.Items.Add (printer.ToString());

}

}
```

Try the above code.Its in c# .net
For more information visit url:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/efaf11bf-f7ae-4167-ba0b-d495b0e21946

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This code help me to find out how many printers attached in my system but I want some information from USB printer i.e. page count, toner value, serial number and printer status. Do you have any idea how to read these information from printers?