# How to detect which documents the user is sending to printer?

Tags: c#, printing, printers

I want to detect which files the user is sending to printer and to get those file's paths.
I read a little about the "PrinterSettings" class, but I haven't found the thing that I was looking for. (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In addition, I read about "Win32_Printer" (WMI class), and I tried the code which was brought there, but I still got nothing (link: [How to get Printer Info in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net))

How can I solve this issue?

Also, I don't want to use some external libraries.

Comment: Is this just for your application or is it system wide(*i.e. any printing done on the computer from any application*)

Comment: @MarkHall - yes, I want to detect any printing done on the computer, from any application.

Comment: then you will need to look at the question I linked to, also look at some of the links in this [Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+monitor+the+print+queue+in+c%23&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=how+to+monitor+the+print+queue+in+c%23&sc=0-31&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=71bf09b424c94cc5b48617c7df9268c4)

Comment: @MarkHall - Ok, thanks ! I'll read about it and see how to work with it.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the tag from the title and the Thanks at the end...