# get list of all install actual printers not virtual

Tags: c#, .net, printers

I want to select only actual install printers not virtual.

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters )
{
    MessageBox.Show(printer);
}
```

Comment: I would look at getting the printer properties to see if there is one (like paper or some setting), that can differentiate.  You can also look at System.Management AND WMI to get printers and their properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Printer Info in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net)

Comment: You mean nothing difference between Actual and virtual printer. I want to select only those printers who is physically connected either direct or by network, not like pdf printer.