# How to check printer Status in C#?

Tags: c#, printing, system.printing

I'm fairly new to printing in C# and am trying to find the current status of a specific printer (if it's offline, if it's out of paper, etc) before printing.

```
LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue printQueue = server.GetPrintQueue("EPSON WF-2540 Series");
MessageBox.Show(printQueue.IsOffline.ToString());
```

The code does seem to successfully find the specified printer but always sees it as online. It doesn't matter if the printer is turned on, turned off, or even unplugged (I use a direct usb connection). Does anybody have any ideas as to what can be causing this? Thank you in advance I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net

Comment: Refer to my response on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974936/632469

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN documentation on [PrintQueue.IsOffline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isoffline.aspx) member (remarks section):

> If the printer does not support a signal with this meaning, then the property is always false.

apparently, it is your case and this property is never set to True.

Comment: Even if printer doesn't support mentioned signal, somehow, control panel printer and devices manage to show the printer is offline!