# Get printer model in C #

Tags: c#, printers

It is possible to get printer model ? .
I can find information about my printer with this request :

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
```

But I am not able to find the model.
For example my printer model is : CLX -4190 Series.

I can not find this information anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Try this out :How to get Printer Info in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net)

Comment: This is exactly what I do . But in all the properties found , there is any information about model.That's why I search  another method

Comment: I don't see `model` inside printer properties in MSDN. So I guess you could comment any those community members :)